# Как запросить подтверждение пользователя перед выходом из приложения?

Tags: java, swing

Как сделать, чтобы при попытке закрыть приложение (любым путём) появлялся диалог с подтверждением "Действительно ли вы хотите закрыть это приложение?" и только если пользователь нажмет "Да", закрыть наше приложение?

Comment: Некорректный вопрос, многие выдергивают шнур из розетки или стреляют из дробовика в монитор :-)

Comment: Стрельнув в монитор приложение не вырубить) Придется потом пинками по системному блоку добить.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
  public void windowClosing(WindowEvent event) {
    if (...) {  // пользователь подтвердил
      System.exit(0);
    } 
  }
});
```

Будет работать при попытке закрыть любым путем.

Comment: Я так понял, под закрытием приложения любым путём не имелось в виду только закрытие окна.. или я ошибся? Я сразу подумал о shutdown hook, но он не годится для графики..

Comment: Ну это событие будет приходить при корректном закрытии приложения. А корректное закрытие всегда будет приводить к попытке закрытия главного окна (т.е. которое JOptionPane.setRootFrame(frame)). Т.е. например, при попытке выключить компьютер когда открыто ваше приложение - диалог появится, но если удалить процесс в таск-маганере или выдернуть шнур, то нет.

Comment: Ну ведь есть ещё сигналы.. Кстати о завершении системы: таким способом не победить, потому что пользователь не успеет ничего ответить: винда завершится быстрее (если это не win7) и просто прибьёт приложение. И отмену не сделать..

Answer (score 0):

Насколько мне известно, нельзя сделать так, чтобы "любым способом". Единственное что можно сделать, это во всех местах, где возможен выход из приложения сделать этот запрос (разумеется используя какое-то способ для переиспользования кода).